# SQL Server and GUID?

Tags: sql, sql-server, guid, ssms

I am trying to run this code :

```
exec myStoredProcedure 
    Cast('c5b48202-36af-4597-9780-5366d4188f55' AS uniqueidentifier), 
    744, 
    1, 
    'test', 
    'Chrysanthemum.jpg', 
    '2012-03-26 16:22:17', 
    1, 
    28402, 
    null
```

But I get the following exception

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'c5b48202-36af-4597-9780-5366d4188f55'.

Why? And how do I fix it?

Comment: you can remove the cast (it will cast it for you), probably cannot have function call in that parameter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently you cant use cast on the parameter list. I just wanted to be sure so I ran a little test:

```
create procedure myProc
@param1 uniqueidentifier
as 
begin
select 1
end


exec myProc Cast('c5b48202-36af-4597-9780-5366d4188f55' AS uniqueidentifier) -- fails
exec myProc 'c5b48202-36af-4597-9780-5366d4188f55' --ok
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do a `CAST` when calling a stored procedure. Either you assign that to a variable before executing the sp, or just call it passing the `VARCHAR` as is (it probably will do the implicit cast just fine).

```
DECLARE @GUID UnIQUEIDENTIFIER
SET @GUID = 'c5b48202-36af-4597-9780-5366d4188f55'

EXEC myStoredProcedure @GUID,  744, 
    1, 
    'test', 
    'Chrysanthemum.jpg', 
    '2012-03-26 16:22:17', 
    1, 
    28402, 
    null
```

Comment: This will give me the following excetpion : Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure myStoredProcedure, Line 0
Error converting data type nvarchar to uniqueidentifier.

Comment: @SnowJim - That is an error inside your stored procedure, but the conversion of the variable works fine (I tested before posting). You must be doing a comparison between datatypes inside your sp that raises this conflict. You should post your code on another question to try to fix it

Comment: @SnowJim, how did you define the first parameter in the stored porc? It appears from the error message that it is defined as an nvarchar not a uniqueidentifier.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a calculation in a EXEC command.

You have to do like this:

```
DECLARE @guid uniqueidentifier

SET @guid = 'c5b48202-36af-4597-9780-5366d4188f55'

exec myStoredProcedure 
    @guid, 
    744, 
    1, 
    'test', 
    'Chrysanthemum.jpg', 
    '2012-03-26 16:22:17', 
    1, 
    28402, 
    null
```